# how to edit AutoConfigUrl registry for proxy pac using script

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, proxy, registry, pac

We are creating a SSL VPN setup and our SSL VPN Gatway does not push pac files to the end users machines. But it do supoort running scripts when user connects and disconnet the ssl vpn.

I have created two batch files placed in system one will get execute at the time of connecting to SSL VPN and other at the time of disconnect to the VPN

Connecting to VPN reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "http://www-abc.com:3132/accelerated_pac_base.pac " /f

Disconnecting to VPN reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "" /f

The same is getting updated in the registry but not in the internet explorer connection settings.

Above, you mentioned that we have to modify the value under [HKEY_USERS\, to rectify brower restart issue.

Is is possible to create a two files ( Loin/Logout ) which could be provided to around 100 users to place in their system in the given path. and that patch would be called from our SSL vpn access gateway and resolve browser restart issue

Thanks
Manpreet Bhuee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the automatic configuration script address in the LAN settings of Internet Explorer 8 with the help of a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872444/is-it-possible-to-change-the-automatic-configuration-script-address-in-the-lan-s)